# How can I reverse the ordering of spacebars #each block

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

A helper `sentencesList` is an array of objects containing an element `text`.

HTML:

```
{{#each sentencesList}}
  {{text}}
{{/each}}
```

CLIENT.JS

```
sentencesList: function() {
    return Session.get(SENTENCES)
}
```

How can I reverse the ordering, i.e the highest index number is shows at the top and the element at index position 0 is at the bottom?

Comment: Assuming it's an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just `reverse` the array:

```
sentencesList: function() {
    return Session.get(SENTENCES).reverse();
}
```

Please note: although `{{#each}}` works on both arrays and cursors, this method is array-specific. So you cannot use it, say, on the return of a `Collection.find()` call. To achieve this with a collection, you will have to use [`sort`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) on the key you want to reverse order from.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reverse more than one array, you could create a generic helper in (say) main.js:

```
Template.registerHelper('reverseArray', (array) => array.reverse());
```

In your template:

```
{{#each (reverseArray sentencesList)}}
  {{text}}
{{/each}}
```

EDIT: Updated code to include parentheses as per Pierre's comment

Comment: Thx for the idea. Just as a side note: I had to put parentheses around the subexpression to make it work: {{#each (reverseArray sentencesList)}}